# How many events are created in the inline event?

Tags: javascript

Basically I use the `addEventListener` function to bind events to an element. But you often see that events are created inline. So `onclick="fnName(this)"` and `onkeyup="fnName()"` etc.

**Questions:** Using the example `<input onkeyup="fnName(this)" />`.

1. is a new event now created for each letter or does the tag parameter onkeyup initialise the event once?
2. Which variant needs less computing time? I assume that addEventListener is more perfomanant, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. New event created on every `keyup`, you can filter for specific keys in you function using if conditions `event.key == "SOME_KEY"`
2. It's Micro-optimization with negligible difference, not much worth. A difference worth mentioning, you can multiple functions on same event using `addEventListener` while it wouldn't work in inline events.

```html
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>

<script>
  function function1() {
    console.log("Function1")
  }

  function function2() {
    console.log("Function2")
  }

  function function3() {
    console.log("Function3")
  }

  function function4() {
    console.log("Function4")
  }

  var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1")
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2")

  btn1.onclick = function1
  btn1.onclick = function2

  btn2.addEventListener("click", function3, false)
  btn2.addEventListener("click", function4, false)
</script>
```

Output in console:

```
Function2
Function3
Function4
```

Note: Both approaches will create a new event on every keyup, thus not making any difference. The comparison can be drawn only for single/equal number of event(s).

*References:*

1. dillionmegida.com/p/inline-events-vs-add-event-listeners
2. [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclic)

Comment: But you can attach multiple inline Events to the tag. So you can watch for multiple events, too.

Comment: @MaikLowrey my bad, I phrased the sentence incorrectly thus changing it's meaning. I've corrected it now in the answer itself!

Comment: No problem :-) But thx for correcting. see u

Comment: Sorry, I have to comment again. I don't think it's a good idea to copy things from other pages and paste them here 1:1 without mentioning the source. https://dillionmegida.com/p/inline-events-vs-add-event-listeners/

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. Thought I did mention the use of online sources, I've now listed them as well.